# Send data to a php function using .ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I know that to send data to a php file using $.ajax is something like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

What I'd like to know is if it is possible to send the data on a specific *function* inside that file. If it is, can you show me how? Thank you.

Comment: you mean send a variable?

Comment: I sense that you're quite confused about what's a PHP script, really. you can't "send the data to a specific function inside a PHP file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by following code.
add one more parameter to your ajax call, like file_name=your_function_name, for instance here i send the ajax request as your data with function_name=getResult, it will call the getResult function in php file.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston",  function_name: "getResult"}
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});

<?php
$function_name = $_POST['function_name']
switch($function_name){
    case $function_name:
        getResult();
        break;
    case $function_name:
        updateFunction();
        break
}
?>
```

switch statement is optimized way when you are having more cases.

Answer (score 1):

Create your some.php PHP file like this:

```
<?php

foo($_POST);
function foo($postData) {
  // Process the data
  var_dump($postData);
}
```

The above code will immediately pass the data that is posted to the given function 'foo'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't, but you could add a query string to the url: someurl.php?function=MyFunction and use $_GET['function'] to find out which function should handle the request.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to use parameter passing via url. A proper post is safer, yet not without risks but way more viable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that you have to check which function you have to call. Also there is no need to pass the `POST` parameters inside function because `$_POST` is `superglobal array` you can access them inside function without passing via parameter.

```
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston", func : 'add' }
```

In `some.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['func']) && $_POST['func'] == 'add') {
   // call function here and pass parameter
   func_add();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add an action paramater to your ajax :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston", action: "action1" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

and in your php file :

```
<?php
if($_POST['action'] == action1) {
  action1(); //Do the function named "action1"
}
?>
```